# How to use scons to build arbitrary recipes?

Tags: python, makefile, scons

I would like an alternative to Make where I can easily use some Python code to generate some intermediate files.

I bumped into Scons that claims to be similar to Make. I would like to translate this kind of Makefile into Scons where the calls to Python will be done into Scons itself.

```
.PHONY all clean mrproper

all: out

A=$(wildcard *.a)
B=$(A:.b=.a)
C=$(B:.c=.b)
D=$(wildcard *.d)
C=$(D:.c=.d)

-include $(wildcard *.dep) 

*.b : *.a
    python -mfoo a2b $< -o $@ -M $@.dep

*.c : *.b
    python -mfoo b2c $< -o $@

*.e : *.d
    python -mfoo d2e $< -o $@

out: $(E) $(C)
    python -mfoo out $^ -o $@

clean: 
    $(RM) $(B) $(C) $(E)

mrproper: clean
    $(RM) out *.dep
```

Is it possible to do it so? I am not interested in a working solution, just the build blocks I need to start.

What I am missing is that Scons offers helpers such as

```
env.Program(target = 'helloworld', source = ["helloworld.c"])
```

Which works with standard extensions (`*.c`, `*.s`, ...). Unfortunately I don't want to make a program, and I want to specify the recipe. Said differently I am looking for something more like this:

```
env.append(env.Recipe(target='%.b', deps=['out/%.a', 'out'], builder=foo_a2b))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you want to write/define your own *Builder*, speaking in SCons parlance. Please have a look at our [ToolsForFools Guide](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools) which tries to explain how you can teach new "build recipes" to SCons. Note, how you can always specify a true Python *callable* (e.g. a function) instead of a mere string for an *Action*. You may also want to check out the [MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) (especially the section about 'Action Objects') and the [User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) for a better and more exhaustive introduction to this build system.

Finally, feel free to join our [User mailing list scons-users@scons.org](http://scons.org/lists.html) and ask follow-up questions there. Our community is always eager to help...